# MVC 3 - View rendered on top of the layout page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper, actionresult, razor, viewcontext

I am having a problem rendering my view in the layout page using mvc 3.

When I render the result using a html helper, my output is on top of everything on the page, but I have used the following

```
HtmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Response
```

I extended the html helper to the **RenderModule** method which gives a module name and execute its **ActionResult** when I want to use it like this:

```
@Html.RenderModule("modulename")
```

It gives me the compile error

> can not convert from void to html string

Therefore, I should use it like this:

`@{ Html.RenderModule("modulename")}`

However, it resulted in writing output on top of page.

What should I do?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: If I understand you correctly that you want to render the result of an action in a view, you should be using the existing `Html.Action()` or `Html.RenderAction()` as appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i have used the "htmlhelper.viewcontext.httpcontext.respone"

That's your problem. You should use:

```
htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer
```